# Managing AWS IAM Pass Role Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Can a user having no direct access to private data or a private resource(say ec2) that has access to that private data, but having access to IAM pass role on all resources, create a new resource(new ec2) with an existing role(on ec2) that provides access to the private data, and gain access to that data?

E.g.

```
DataA, DataA-Access-Role, DataA-Accessible-EC2Instance
```

Now, `UserB` does not have access to `DataA` and `DataA-Accessible-EC2Instance` but had access to create a new EC2 instance and pass `DataA-Access-Role`. Is this a clear loophole?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you, but if `UserB` can create an instance and attached the `DataA-Access-Role` role to it, then the instance can access `DataA`. So if the `UserB` can login to the instance, he/she will also be able to access `DataA`.

Comment: The situation you describing here is called "Privilege Escalation". There are plenty of examples of how to exploit and prevent it if you just google the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be very dangerous to grant `iam:PassRole` permissions to users.

Preferably, such permissions should always be **limited to specific Roles** that they can pass.

The reason is that a user could create an Amazon EC2 instance that uses the Role, so they would effectively gain the permissions associated with the Role.

There are [many articles on this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=passrole+iam+escalation) that can recommend ways to reduce such exposure.